# Using the arguments object in functions

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

Why does the foo function work fine.

```
function foo (a,b) {
  return arguments.length;
}
```

But, the boo function returns undefined is not a function, even though I pass arguments in the function.

```
function boo (a,b) {
  return arguments.slice(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` is not an array, but an array-like object. Many array methods work on array-like objects, because they expect an object with numeric properties, and a `length` property, such as `arguments`. You can use the built-in functions by using `call` and passing the object as the `this` value:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
//^ args is a real array now
```

This works with other methods as well, like `reduce`:

```
function sum(/*...args*/) {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(x, y){return x + y})
}
```

Comment: How does using the call method on the slice function turn the arguments object into an array?

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is an object and **not** an `array`. If you print it and see, you can see an object:

```
function foo (a,b) {
    console.log(arguments);
}

foo(10,20);

o/p: { '0': 10, '1': 20 }
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments),

> This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the
>   function, the first entry's index starting at 0. For example, if a
>   function is passed three arguments, you can refer to the argument as
>   follows:
>
> ```
>  arguments[0] arguments[1] arguments[2]
> ```

It does **not** have any Array properties except `length`.

So, `return arguments.slice(0);` would fail, since `slice` belongs to the `prototype` of an `array`.